# Grouping plugin initializations and functions into a single script

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-plugins

I have a very basic question about grouping (jQuery) plugin initializations-- and really any type of script-- into a single script throughout a website: in my templates, I typically have a "tools.js" file that includes various plugin initializations, click functions and the like. For the sake of ease, neatness and number of server requests, I like to keep these functions/script calls centralized in a single file, however, on certain pages, various scripts won't apply-- say, a fitvids.js script initialization that might be used on one page with a video, and not on another. Thus, I'm wondering if this is problematic in any way, i.e. can this create problems if a certain library isn't included on a given page-- but it's initialization *is*-- or a selector referenced in a click function is not present on a given page?

Thanks for any insight here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my design, I will have only shared code like plugin definitions or common utility methods shared between pages. The functional code like event handlers or plugin initialization for each page will be kept separate.

If there is a cross cutting concern in multiple pages then it will be either converted as a plugin or as a utility method which will be placed in a shared file but the actual usage will be done for each page separately.

Comment: Thanks Arun-- does doing say create any problems that you can think of, though? What if a plugin initialization is called and the underlying library is not present? Can this interrupt/disturb the functionality of other scripts on the page?

Comment: @nickpish It won't create any problems if everything goes fine... but assume tomorrow you want to make some changes in a particular event handler... it will be a testing nightmare since you don't know which other pages uses it

Answer (score 1):

If the selector is not present in the DOM and has a click handler in js, it should not be a problem. The reason behind is that the click function is never triggered. It is an issue if the attached handler is executed by any chance and js can't find your selector.